# Spring JMS with Spring boot , Conflicting beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am creating a Spring JMS listener with Spring boot, But I keep getting this error:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: queueConnectionFactory,queueConnectionFactoryExtra,targetConnectionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
```

Whereever I read it was resolved using `@Qualifier` annotation but that doesn't seem to work for me, please help. Below is my class:-

```
@Configuration
public class ListenerContainer{ 


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Qualifier("queueConnectionFactory")
@Bean(name="planListenerContainerFactoryExtra")
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("queueConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory,@Qualifier("queue") MQQueue queue, ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(queueConnectionFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

    return factory;
}




@Qualifier("targetConnectionFactory")
@Bean(name="queueConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory(@Qualifier("targetConnectionFactory")  MQQueueConnectionFactory targetConnectionFactory) {
    CachingConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    ....
    return queueConnectionFactory;

}

@Bean(name="targetConnectionFactory")
public MQQueueConnectionFactory targetConnectionFactory() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory targetConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

    return targetConnectionFactory;

}

@Bean(name="queue")
public MQQueue queue() {
    MQQueue queue = new MQQueue();
    .....
    return queue;

}

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create those yourself, Spring Boot already does that for you. Next to that your configuration is a mess. `@Qualifier` on a method or an a method argument are quite different!.

Comment: I only had @Qualifier in the arguments, I just tried putting it over the method as well after reading it somewhere. If Spring boot creates it for me   what names do I provide for queue manager, queue , port and other things in application.properties. I know Spring boot does it for "Active Queue" if you just have that jar in your classpath, but I am using IBM MQ series

Comment: to the second part of your question I want this to be a spring bean as well:- MQQueueConnectionFactory. As soon as I remove @Bean from my targetConnectionFactory() method it all works fine, because I think that Spring considers MQQueueConnectionFactory and ConnectionFactory to be of same type

Comment: Put `@Primary` on your `CachingConnectionFactory`... Still Spring Boot does those things already for you, with the auto-config. So I suggest working with the framework.

Comment: thank you, it solves problem to some extent but I have two listeners in application listening to queues on different managers for the second JmsListenerContainerFactory it now complains that more than one primary beans have bean defined. I have read the JMS part here: "http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jms-annotated" but there is no mention of how spring does it all for you, there are blogs that show it but that is using "Active MQ" and none of them use multiple listeners across different queue managers. Could you point me to any document.

Comment: That is a whole different question. But Spring Boot already creates a `jmsListenerContainerFactory` so all you need to do is add methods annotated with `@JmsListener`.

Comment: ok thank you for your help. I will try to find that out.